# Java: how to limit argument's values that can be passed to a method

Tags: java

Suppose I have a method that takes one `int` as a argument,

suppose the method expects only the values **0, 1, 2** and **not other int**.

Is there a way to "force" the method to accept only 0, 1, 2?

Comment: You can always throw an `IllegalArgumentException` if the argument is invalid, of course.

Comment: You could use AOP (Aspect Oriented Programming), like the AspectJ library: create some annotation that indicates that one of the arguments should be restricted, and create a Joinpoint that matches on that annotation, and create an Advice that checks the value. However - this will do only runtime checking. If you want static, compile-time, checking, you need to create your own datatype.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You would have to create a custom data type that can only take the values `0`, `1` and `2`. You can't use an ordinary `int`.

In this case you could use an `enum`:

```
enum ZeroOneOrTwo {
    ZERO(0),
    ONE(1),
    TWO(2);
    public final int val;
    private ZeroOneOrTwo(int val) {
        this.val = val;
    }
}
```

and use it as follows:

```
void myMethod(ZeroOneOrTwo arg) {
    System.out.println("Int value: " + arg.val);
}
```

If you're forced to take an `int` as argument (if you're implementing an interface for instance) you can resort to throwing an `IllegalArgumentException` if the given value is out of range. But generally you would want to let the compiler catch the problem rather than having to deal with it at runtime.

Comment: But if you change the order of the enum, the ordinal will break

Comment: If the method should accept 0, 1 or 2, chances are that they actually represent something else than quantities, in which case ZERO, ONE and TWO would have more descriptive names where order is irrelevant.

Comment: @aioobe please aioobe I am not sure how would I use that enum to represent 3 ints

Comment: @aioobe satill don't get it :-((, maybe it was clearer before, before you deleted the costructor

Comment: Reverted to the approach using a constructor and a field in the enum.

Comment: May you can put a method named `valueOf(int)` which throws `IllegalArgumentException` and use it within the origin method takes an `int`.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe not applicable in every case (but you didn't specify further what you're trying to accomplish, so maybe it's worth a shot), but maybe you might consider creating three methods instead of one? Or using inheritance, since you're using an OOP language?

For example, instead of *coding* some information into an `int`, it might be better coding style to change it.

So instead of ...

```
void addEmployee(int type) {
    switch(type) {
        case 0: // add regular eymploee
        case 1: // add manager
        case 2: // add CEO
    }
}
```

... consider this ...

```
void addRegularEmployee() { 
    // ... 
}
void addManager() { 
    // ... 
}
void addCEO() { 
    // ... 
}
```

... or even ...

```
void add(Employee e) {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As @JonSkeet commented, you can throw an instance of `IllegalArgumentException`. I can't find the way to translate `the way to force`, though.

```
void giveMeZeroOneOrTwo(final int value) {

    if (value != 0 && value != 1 && value != 2) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("unacceptable value: " + value);
    }

    // now you can read the method name, huh?
}
```

Or `Bean Validation` may work for you.

```
void giveMeZeroOneOrTwo(@Min(0) @Max(2) final int value) {
}
```

Well, using enum maybe good approach, and I would to like this.

```
enum Magic {
    ONE(1),
    TWO(2),
    THREE(3);
    public static Magic valueOf(int value) {
        for (final Magic v : values()) {
            if (v.value == value) {
                return v;
            }
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("undefined value: " + value);
    }
    private Magic(int value) {
        this.value = value
    }
    private final int value;
}
```

Now the method which **takes an `int`** can be verified.

```
void giveMeOneTwoOrThree(final int value) {
    // still throws an IllegalArgumentException
    final Magic magic = Magic.valueOf(value);
}
```

Comment: The approach is obvious: make that restriction visible to the type system by constructing a type with only three distinct values. And that's precisely what the enum-based approach achieves.